# Target and Copy selection from one Excel file to another - C#

Tags: c#, excel

Quite some time ago I created a Powershell script to do what I wrote in the title: Copying a selection from File-A to File-B. The way I need it (and the way I did it) is to open a "Template" file when the application starts, the user selects a range, then they have 4 option buttons. The most-used is "Copy Selection", which will copy the contents of the range selection to all of the Excel files in a specific directory. With Powershell this works (although it took a long time to figure out) with the following code:

```
$strRow = $Excel.ActiveCell.Row
$strColumn = $Excel.ActiveCell.Column
$Range = $sourceWorksheet.Cells.item($strRow,$strColumn)
$Range.Select
$Excel.Selection.Copy() | Out-Null
foreach ($item in $files) 
{               
$destinationPath = $item.FullName
$destinationWorkBook = $Excel.WorkBooks.Open($destinationPath)              
$destinationWorkSheet = $destinationWorkBook.worksheets.item(1)
$destRange = $destinationWorkSheet.Cells.item($strRow,$strColumn)
$destRange.Select
$destRange.PasteSpecial() | Out-Null
$destinationWorkBook.Close($true)
}
```

That works fine, but I obviously want to get rid of Powershell. I've created a C# application using WPF that will look and work great, I just have to get the logic working. I can't seem to actually target a range selection. I've tried a number of methods and properties, and none seem to get what I need. I can get the actual "selection" cell, but I can't get any type of range.  The object I retrieve generally have Rows and Columns properties, so if need-be I guess I could extrapolate that information...but there's gotta be a better way.

Right now the closest thing I have would be to use `Application.ActiveCell.Copy();` (or Select), but it seems to have issues when I try pasting it.

Any ideas? I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working.

EDIT: I've solved my own issue...sorry if anyone wasted time looking at this.

I'm an idiot...I spent a bit more time and figured out how to do it. The below code works perfectly - the main issue I was running into is that using `Worksheet.Cells.item` requires a bracket. I still have to loop through the documents to apply to, but this should take care of the actual logic:

```
int intRow = myApp.ActiveCell.Row;
int intCol = myApp.ActiveCell.Column;
myApp.Selection.Copy();

Range destRange = mySheet.Cells.Item[intRow,intCol];
destRange.PasteSpecial();
```

Hope I didn't waste anyone's time and they can figure this out now!